# USB c++ development environment

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, portability, environment

I need to set up a USB with a the necessary programs to have a portable development environment. I use 64bit Windows 7 at home and 32bit Windows XP at work, where I will use this the most.
How would one go about creating one of these? I mostly do game programming so I have to include libraries in this.

I'd prefer to use the command line for compiling instead of putting a huge IDE on the drive. My computer at works isn't top of the line.

So far, I've only found what editor I would use. Notepad++.
Other than that, I got next to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, it seems to be exactly what you're looking for:

http://code.google.com/p/pocketcpp/

As for the libraries, you could compress them on the USB device if space is really tight and decompress on the target computer. It all depends on how big your device is in terms of capacity.